# Is there an 'opposite' neurotransmitter to dopamine?

Tags: biochemistry, neuroscience, brain

Dopamine is a neurotransmitter  (i.e. chemical) in the brain that gives us great feeling. From [here](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/what-is-dopamine):

> Dopamine plays a role in how we feel pleasure. It's a big part of our unique human ability to think and plan. It helps us strive, focus, and find things interesting.

Is there any chemical(s) released in the brain that have an opposite effect to dopamine, that is, some chemical that makes us feel bad?

Comment: There's [MOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoamine_oxidase) which break down dopamine and therefore has sort of the opposite effect by reducing the dopamine-levels, sometimes even under the normal level - which basically induces the opposite of high levels of dopamine

Answer (score 1):

The release of dopamine has a positive effect on the reward center in the nucleus accumbens. The neuron that releases the dopamine can be inhibited by other neurons, so there gets less dopamine released.

The response elicited by a neurotransmitter, either excitatory or inhibitory, is determined by its receptor on the postsynaptic cell. ~https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21607/def-item/A7678/